# DataTable RowFilter on Time component of DateTime column

Tags: c#, datetime, rowfilter

I have DataColumn named `Created` of type DateTime in a DataTable and have created a RowFilter expression to return only Rows created after, say, 10 pm on any day:

```
"SUBSTRING(Convert(Created, 'System.String'),11,8) >= '" + cStartTime + "'"
```

This should convert the DateTime to a `System.String`, extract the time element as an 8 character sub-string and compare that with a known string value (cStartTime), e.g. "22:00:00".  It should return one row, but returns none.

Comment: So `cStartTime` is a `String` `"22:00:00"`?

Comment: Yes, a String.  As Tim Schmelter points out that could be a problem.  A Pity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use this approach, it's very error-prone and not readable to convert a `DateTime` to `String` and use sub-string, even if it worked now it could break in future(f.e. if the system is using a different culture). Instead i suggest to use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
var filtered = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
               let created = row.Field<DateTime>("Created")
               where created.Hour >= 22
               select row;
```

If you want a `DataRow[]` use `filtered.ToArray()`. If you want a new `DataTable` use  `filtered.CopyToDataTable()`.

Comment: I'm using Vulcan.NET which doesn't yet handle Linq.  A good language, but not fully up to speed with C# yet.  But, a good point about culture differences.  But it didn't work anyway, so "Error Prone" seems to be true.  Thanks. AJB.